# Which houseplants are most toxic to cats?

Tags: cats, diet, plants

[Numerous](https://plantsncats.com/toxic-plants-for-cats/) ordinary house plants have been marked as toxic to cats. Then again trace amounts on the claws that it licks off is different from eating the plant like they sometime do to [grass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lolium) to obtain fiber.

I'm looking for a similar list but with toxicity indicated. Can some plants kill a cat if it consumes a couple of leaves?

Comment: May I ask why you need to know the relative toxicity? Isn't it enough to know that plant X is toxic to cats and you shouldn't have one around cats?

Comment: @Elmy Relative toxicity might inform the decision whether a plant needs to be removed right away, i.e. thrown in the trash, or if there are a couple of days to find a new home for the plant. Of course, if relative toxicity is unknown, assuming the plant to be lethal even in trace amounts is the best course of action. Good question imho, as many new pet guardians will struggle with the decision of throwing away existing plants in their homes versus finding new owners for the plants.

Comment: @Elmy I know that beer, city air, city traffic, stressful work environment are bad for human health but still have them around. While some substances/environments are somewhat more dangerous. So I want to develop knowledge for when I take the cat outside and it starts chomping on some random weed to have some chance of recognizing it and some estimate of danger.